# Task during startup of mixed mode application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a native C++ application that implements certain features in .NET and WPF. Some of these WPF screen get loaded at startup. However, one of my requirement requires making REST calls during startup before any of the WPF screens are loaded. I am using .NET 4.0 TPL and using C# Task for making the REST calls.

My question is that is it safe to create C# tasks using TPL in mixed mode applications without a WPF/WinForms UI context. I observe that the SynchronizationContext is null in the main thread at the time of making the REST calls in the Task, and I can't find a suitable documentation about how C# tasks usage in case of mixed mode programs with no UI context

Comment: It should work, what's your problem?

Comment: I don't see enough documentation / best practices around using C# Tasks in mixed mode programs, e.g. how to handle null SynchronizationContext.

Comment: This is an imagined problem, not a real one.  A WPF needs a synchronization provider because its UI is not thread-safe.  You don't have an UI yet.  Come back when it blows up, you know where to find us :)

Answer (score 0):

A null SynchronizationContext will not cause you problems.  A console application (for example) has null SynchronizationContext.